# Ambiguous intermediate result

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, typeclass

Suppose I have a typeclass, two instances, and a function defined as follows.

```
class C c where
  newC :: String -> c
  showC :: c -> String

data C1 = C1 String  

instance C C1 where
  newC string = C1 string  
  showC (C1 string) = string

data C2 = C2 String  

instance C C2 where
  newC string = C2 string  
  showC (C2 string) = string


topFn :: String -> String 
topFn = showC . newC
```

When loaded, GHC produces an "Ambiguous type" error,

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘c0’ arising from a use of ‘showC’
prevents the constraint ‘(C c0)’ from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘c0’ should be.
These potential instances exist:
   instance C C1 -- Defined at ambigType.hs:8:10
   instance C C2 -- Defined at ambigType.hs:14:10
```

I understand that the intermediate value could be either `C1` or `C2` and that without further information GHC has no way to determine which it should be.

Writing two versions of `topFn` solves the problem.

```
topFn1 :: String -> String 
topFn1 = showC . (newC :: String -> C1)

topFn2 :: String -> String 
topFn2 = showC . (newC :: String -> C2)
```

But since these are essentially identical functions, this seems like an ugly solution. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `TypeApplications`, `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, `ExplicitForall`, and `ScopedTypeVariables` extensions. Then, modify `topFn` to be

```
topFn :: forall a. C a => String -> String 
topFn = showC . newC @a
```

Then, you can call `topFn` using an explicit type-application: `topFn @C1 "calling the C1 variant"` and `topFn @C2 "calling the C2 variant"`. If you want, you can define:

```
topFn1 = topFn @C1
topFn2 = topFn @C2
```

Comment: Thanks. When I add the extensions and then call `(topFn @C1) "abc"` I get two errors `Pattern syntax in expression context: top@C1` and `Did you mean to enable TypeApplications?` I did add the `TypeApplications` extension and the rest of them..

Comment: Did you enable `TypeApplications` where you are _calling_ the function? Possibly GHCi?

Comment: It's all in one file with this line at the top: `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ExplicitForAll, ScopedTypeVariables #-}` Then I do `> topFn @C1 "abc"`. It doesn't help to do `> {-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ExplicitForAll, ScopedTypeVariables #-}` first.

Comment: Assuming `> {-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ExplicitForAll, ScopedTypeVariables #-}` is entered in GHCi, it won't work. From within GHCi, you can do `> :set -XTypeApplications` instead.

Comment: Aha! That did it!

Comment: Is it possible to pass the type as an argument to the function call?

Comment: Actually, `TypeApplications` is doing exactly that: passing in the type as an argument to the function call. If you are looking for a way to pass the type as a _regular_ argument to the function call, then no. That requires full-blown dependent types. Note that this is actually exactly what Idris does.